# JMeter - Extracting the 'code' from response header

Tags: authentication, jmeter, extract, correlation, response-headers

I am trying to extract the 'code' from the response header of GET request.  The code is needed to authenticate a sign in. I am able to extract the 'code'- however it only works about 50% of the time. I have tried to use different Timers, thinking it could be an issue with having to wait for the page to load, but that doesnt seem to make much of a difference.

Here is an example the response header which contains the 'code' we need.  It is extracted from the "AUTHORIZE - get CODE-0" request: /callback/loa-1?code=8bd92bd0-9c35-4c77-8c1a-a205a32b44d4&state=e10ccxxxxxxxxxxxx45yyyyyyyyy6zzzzzf

Where the 'code' is 8bd92bd0-9c35-4c77-8c1a-a205a32b44d4

In the request that is Failed in the Results Tree, the "AUTHORIZE - get CODE-0" returns different response headers than the one that was successful, specifically the "Location" which contains the URL we extract the 'code' from.

Here is the Results Tree:[image: Results Tree]

Thread Group settings:[image: Thread Group]

HTTP Header Manager:[image: HTTP Header Manager]

HTTP Cookie Manager:[image: HTTP Cookie Manager]

HTTP Cache Manager:[image: HTTP Cache Manager]

HTTP Request Defaults:[image: HTTP Request Defaults]

HTTP Authorization Manager:[image: HTTP Authorization Manager]

I am able to extract the 'code'- however it only works about 50% of the time. I have tried to use different Timers, thinking it could be an issue with having to wait for the page to load, but that doesnt seem to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You've shared a lot of useless screenshots instead of sharing the only one which makes sense: the [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) you're using to get the code.

In case of [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) the relevant regular expression should be something like `code=([a-f0-9]{8}(?:-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8})`

[image]

In case of [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) you can just use `code=` as the left boundary and `&` as the right boundary (however if the order of parameters changes the extraction will fail)

[image]

If you still experience the issue - check response details of the request which returns the "code" using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and what is being stored into the JMeter Variable using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler).

Comment: @PeterSmith I am able to extract the code using the RegEx extractor, however it only works about half of the time... RegEx used is "code=([^&]+)" applied to Response Headers.  It seems that the request I am trying to extract the Code from will return different response headers half the time for whatever reason.

Comment: You can [save JMeter response headers and body for the failed requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) using [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) and compare what is being returned in cases of failure.